# Excel: Find most right (last) occurrence of a value with VBA in a row

Tags: excel, vba, ms-office

In an Excel sheet I want to find, using VBA, the rightmost occurrence of a value in a specific row.

Example: Say I have the following values in row 3 (cells delimited by spaces in this example):

```
1 2 1 5 1 5 7 1 4 5 6
```

Now I want to get the column number of the rightmost occurrence of the value `1`. The answer is 8.

How do I get this answer in an efficient way and with a single command? Can i do this with `Range.Find()`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes you can:

```
range("3:3").Find(what:=1,searchorder:=xlbycolumns,searchdirection:=xlPrevious).column
```

if you know there will be at least one occurrence of 1 (otherwise you should test the result range before trying to refer to its column)